# Persist Cookies across applications ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, single-sign-on, nshttpcookie

I am trying to persist cookies across 4 applications, I am aware with iOS 8 NSUserDefaults can be used to persist data across application groups using

```
[[NSUserDefaults alloc] initWithSuiteName:@"<group identifier>"];
```

Can cookies be available across applications in iOS7? And iOS 8 without using extensions and app groups?

Answer (score 0):

Apple allows for applications with the entitlement for the same app group added under Capabilities in your Xcode project.  Without that you can't access another application's sandbox.  You would need to use app groups.  App groups are available in ios7 and later. [Link to docs here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSUserDefaults/initWithSuiteName:)